# How to get an Integer Value from a ComboBox using a DataTable as its DataSource

Tags: vb.net, casting, datatable, valuemember

I am using code similar to this to populate a combobox with items from a database.  The display works fine, but when I try to get the `combobox.SelectedValue` it is returning a DataRowView, where I need an integer.  Obviously this is becuase I haven't casted the value to an integer, but the function, `CInt(cboPosition.SelectedValue)` is throwing an InvalidCastException.  Is there any way that I can get the ValueMember's type to be an Integer?

```
Dim cn As New SqlConnection(CreditDisputesLogConn)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("CustomersLookup", cn)
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Try
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        uxCustomerName.DataSource = dt
        uxCustomerName.DisplayMember = "CustomerName"
        uxCustomerName.ValueMember = "CustomerID"
        uxCustomerName.SelectedIndex = -1
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        cn.Close()
        cn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select both fields `ID` and `Text` in your SQL.

If you did select `ID`, you can use `MsgBox TypeName(cboPosition.SelectedValue)` to determine the type of the selected value. This might help you with debugging.

---

EDIT: If `SelectedValue` returns a `DataRowView`, you can access the `ID` field like this:

```
Dim myDataRowView As DataRowView = DirectCast(cboPosition.SelectedValue, DataRowView)
Dim myId as Integer = CInt(myDataRowView("CustomerID"))
```

As to why `SelectedValue` returns the `DataRowView` although a correct `ValueMember` is set, I have no idea...

---

EDIT2: I found the reason why `SelectedValue` returns the whole row instead of just the `ValueMember`: You [have to set the properties in the "right" order](http://madhawa.blogspot.com/2005_05_01_archive.html#111519214339219920), i.e.:

```
    uxCustomerName.DisplayMember = "CustomerName"
    uxCustomerName.ValueMember = "CustomerID"
    uxCustomerName.DataSource = dt
```

(First `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`, *then* `DataSource`.)

Comment: As I said, the code above is only similar.  The stored procedure I'm using _does_ return the ID and Description fields; that part works fine.  The issue is that the type of the SelectedValue is `DataRowView`

Comment: I edited the answer to show the actual code for the lookup that I'm using.

Comment: Just to make sure: You *are* using `SelectedValue` and not `SelectedItem`, right? I've updated my answer.

Comment: Updated my answer with (what I believe to be) the final solution.